# Problems with task completion conditions

Tags: workflow, tasks

I have tried probably 1 billion different possibilities but nothing seems to work.

I have a SharePoint 2010 workflow that starts an approval process with GROUP X as soon as any user creates a new item in a list.

Everything seems to work except the approval process. I need that as soon as 50% of the members of GROUP X approve the task, the tasking process finishes no matter how many participants have not voted yet. For this reason, I have created the configurations as seen in the pictures below.

In “**Change the completion condition for this task process**”:

[image]

In “**Change the behavior of a single task**”:

[image]

The problem is that I am ALWAYS getting the REJECTED response in the tests. There is only myself in the GROUP X and if I approve it (100% of approval) it still rejects. It should be changing the Variable IsItemApproved to YES and then triggering the first step in the picture below. However, it is not.

I have no idea what else to try.

In “**Change the behavior of the overall task process**”:

[image]

Comment: This might be completely off the wall (I haven't done much work with approval workflows/tasks, so I really don't know), but is the percentage really a number 0 - 100?  I have often seen percentages represented by a decimal value 0 - 1.  If that's the case then 50% = 0.5.

Comment: It seems that the numbers are 0 - 100. I just figured out that this approval system does not work when there is only one approval in the group. I have no idea why.